# C++ DLL return Mat to C#

Tags: c#, c++, opencv

I have a DLL build in C++, and will return Mat object.
That picture info is 384*384*24 color.

C# code

```
Bitmap a = new Bitmap(384, 384, 3 * 384, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, test1());
pictureBox0.Image = a;
```

C++ code

```
uchar*  DLL_EXPORT test1(void)
{
    Mat OriginalImg = imread("c:\\20100812133.jpg", 1 );

    return OriginalImg.data;
}
```

upon code are ok, but I want to read the picture in gray.
I will do some image process(ex:Threshod), and convert to color,
and return to C# and show it!

C++ code

```
uchar*  DLL_EXPORT test0(void)
{
    Mat OriginalImg = imread("c:\\20100812133.jpg", 0 );
    threshold(OriginalImg,OriginalImg,0,255,THRESH_OTSU);
    cvtColor(OriginalImg,OriginalImg,CV_GRAY2BGR);
    return OriginalImg.data;
}
```

The c++ code fails, can you help?

---

updata
http://ppt.cc/h2SI the picture is fail, i think the cause is memory.
I fix c# code the 3st parmet 3*384 to 2*384.
C# is run ok, but picture is break like this http://ppt.cc/IRfd

--
updata

```
Bitmap a = new Bitmap(384, 384, 1 * 384, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, test0());
Bitmap a = new Bitmap(384, 384, 2 * 384, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, test0());
Bitmap a = new Bitmap(384, 384, 3 * 384, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, test0());

Bitmap a = new Bitmap(384, 384, 2 * 384, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, test0());
Bitmap a = new Bitmap(384, 384, 3 * 384, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, test0());
Bitmap a = new Bitmap(384, 384, 4 * 384, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, test0());
```

i try six , run are ok, but picture are break.

Comment: What kind of failure? Details, please.

Comment: You need to set a diffrent picture format here PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb or convert your image data to the format described by this data type

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a pointer to a local variable that's already been freed, that will never be reliable.

You need to arrange for the `Mat` object to live long enough for the `Bitmap` constructor to copy its contents.  The simplest approach would be to use C++/CLI, then you can return a .NET Bitmap from C++:

```
Bitmap^ MyImageProcessor::test0(void)
{
    Mat OriginalImg = imread("c:\\20100812133.jpg", 0 );
    threshold(OriginalImg,OriginalImg,0,255,THRESH_OTSU);
    cvtColor(OriginalImg,OriginalImg,CV_GRAY2BGR);
    return gcnew Bitmap(384,
                        384,
                        3 * 384,
                        PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb,
                        IntPtr(OriginalImg.data)
                       );
}
```

Comment: gcnew or new ? if i use the code, i necessary  in visual c++? no GCC?

Comment: @wi yu: The C++/CLI extensions such as `gcnew` are only available in Visual C++.  But aren't you already using Visual Studio, since part of the code is C#?  Anyway, C++/CLI is not necessary, but creating the `Bitmap` before the `Mat` object dies IS important.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the imread success?

```
Mat OriginalImg = imread("c:\\20100812133.jpg", 0 );
if(OriginalImg.empty())
    return NULL;
```

And in C# (Note that the code I wrote is not necessarily correct, but you get the idea)

```
char* imgData = test1;

if(imgData == Null)
{
 // do something smart
}

Bitmap a = new Bitmap(384, 384, 3 * 384, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, imgData);
pictureBox0.Image = a;
```

This is one of the most frequent mistakes you can do in programming -  and one of the most annoying

Comment: I'm sure the picture path is OK.
because the test1 function return right picture.
http://ppt.cc/IRfd like this.
the up picture is right picture.

Comment: But I am sure your programming model is flawed - even if it works in this scenario. Without it, you'll never know whether it is actually a wrong path or something else.

Comment: i test your idea, and the c++ return not NULL.

Comment: i add your idea in code, thx! and how to fix my code, i want to show picture right!